# Regular expression to find CreateGraphics calls that do not have a using block

Tags: c#, .net, regex, gdi+

I've been tasked with finding all of the calls to CreateGraphics in our codebase that are not enclosed by a using block and adding using blocks around them.

I know I can find these with a regular expression, but I need some help with the syntax.

I need a regex that I can use with *Visual Studio 2010's Find In Files* dialog that will find any line that contains **CreateGraphics** that does not start with **using**.

Match this:

```
  pnlSearchAndBrowseButton.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(lineLight, 2, h - 1, w - 1, h - 1);
```

But not this:

```
  using (Graphics g = label.CreateGraphics())
```

Either line may or may not have whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: How big is your code-base?  Would a 'find usages' return more than 50 or so?

Comment: It's enormous.  Although I can find references on CreateGraphics, I'm midway through this effort and I'd like a regex that can exclude the work I've already done so I can be sure I'm not missing any.

Comment: Keep in mind Graphics are also commonly created using Graphics.FromImage.  There are a few other ways as well which are less common.  These all should be disposed.

Comment: @Moozhe: Thanks for the info.  I'm am looking for other GDI+ resources that aren't being disposed properly as part of this effort.  CreateGraphics calls are just one example, but once I find a RegEx that works, I can use it for the others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

Find In Files -> Find Options -> Use -> Regular Expressions

Then put this regex in "Find what: -> `^~(:Wh*using).*CreateGraphics`

Complete list of regex ->

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: -1: please don't post .NET 1.1 links. Readers will find themselves stuck in the midst of decade-old information.

Comment: I tried this in VS2010: it returns also the lines with "using..."

Comment: @woohoo - There is nothing preventing lines with "using" coming through except when its preceeded by the BOL and whitespace (the OP's requirement). Works for me in VS2008.

Comment: @John Saunders - I have no idea what you are talking about, but you seem to be off topic.

Comment: @sln: the list of links doesn't really help. Just take your .NET 1.1 link and remove the part in parentheses

Comment: Could you tell me what I would need to change to search for other criteria, such as "new Pen"?  I tried this but it didn't return any results: ^~(:Wh*using)*new Pen

Comment: @Avalanchis - If 'using' is still the criteria, `^~(:Wh*using).*new:Wh+Pen` roughly translates to `^(?!\s*using).*new\s+Pen` means get lines with 'new <1 or more spaces> Pen' that do not have BOL plus optional whitespace then 'using' before it. If 'using' is not the criteria, then just `new:Wh+Pen` should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *No longer relevant as the problem description changed in a quite significant way. I will still leave this here as it is (in my eyes) still a viable solution to the actual problem.*

---

```
(?<!using.+)\.CreateGraphics\(
```

might work. PowerShell test:

```
PS> $re='(?<!using.+)\.CreateGraphics\('
PS> 'pnlSearchAndBrowseButton.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(lineLight, 2, h - 1, w - 1, h - 1);',
>> 'using (Graphics g = label.CreateGraphics())' -match $re
>>
pnlSearchAndBrowseButton.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(lineLight, 2, h - 1, w - 1, h - 1);
```

One note of caution, the regex will not work in languages that don't support variable-length lookbehind. But .NET does, as can be seen above.

Or even not using a regex (blasphemy!):

```
if (line.Contains(".CreateGraphics(") && !line.Contains("using")) ...
```

Or do a two-pass variant:

```
lines.Select(l => l.Contains(".CreateGraphics(")).Select(l => !l.Contains("using"))
```

Comment: The first example did not match any lines.  The second example does not exclude lines that start with "using".

Comment: @Joey: I don't think that VS' Find in Files supports look-behinds. Its support for regexes is very limited.

Comment: Do I need to do something different to use the first example in the VS 2010 Find in Files dialog (besides enabling the regex option)?

Comment: Igor, that addition came *after* my answer ... I was under the impression that they simply wrote a little tool to do the job. This is something that's a short one-liner in PowerShell and other scripting languages or even a ten-liner in C#. Nothing where I'd think of working hours to find something that works in the limited regex subset of VS's Find in Files.

Comment: Sorry, I added the clarification about VS 2010 Find in Files after my initial question was posted.

Comment: I didn't realize the Find in Files regex support was so limited.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the command line tool FINDSTR:

findstr /N /S /C:CreateGraphics *.cs | findstr /V /C:using

That'll give you a list of all the lines that contain "CreateGraphics" but not "using".